# How to free up swap space heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have one app that runs on Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1.3 on Heroku. What I realize after I leave it run for a while I see there a lot of swap space used. I don't know why. And also I cause Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded).

[image]

Is there any ways to free up swap space?

Comment: Samnang, did Brad's suggestion work? I have the same problem with 2.1.3.

Comment: It didn't help for me, but some people responded it helps. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the new garbage collector in Ruby 2.1.3 allows for more memory growth in exchange for performance (fewer garbage collection cycles). It defaults to allowing the memory to double.

The solution is to set the growth factor to 1.3 from the default of 2.0

$ heroku config:set RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR=1.3

For more info, see https://discussion.heroku.com/t/tuning-rgengc-2-1-on-heroku/359/15